# I use switch case and enum for changing the button's text, but it's not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

So I am trying to use switch case and enum for changing the button's text since I don't want to use too many "if" statements. However, the button text is not properly displayed. For example, actionButton1.text isn't "Save Game" but "SAVE_GAME".

**ActionType.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum ActionType {
    SAVE_GAME,
    LOAD_GAME,
    PAUSE_GAME
};

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Action", menuName = "Project/New Action")]
public class Action : ScriptableObject
{
    public ActionType actionType;
    public string actionName;

    public void Awake() {
        switch (actionType) {
            case ActionType.SAVE_GAME:
                actionName = "Save Game";
            break;

            case ActionType.LOAD_GAME:
                actionName = "Load Game";
            break;

            case ActionType.PAUSE_GAME:
                actionName = "Pause Game";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**System.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class System : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text actionButton1;
    public Text actionButton2;
    public Text actionButton3;

    public Action action1;
    public Action action2;
    public Action action3;

    private void Start() {
        refreshAction();
    }

    private void refreshAction() {
        actionButton1.text = action1.actionName;
        actionButton2.text = action2.actionName;
        actionButton3.text = action3.actionName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `actionName` of your stored scriptable object truly "Save Game"? (Take a look in the inspector.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would use lazy evaluation

```
public class Action : ScriptableObject
{
    public ActionType actionType;
    public string actionName
    {
        get
        {
            switch(actionType)
            {
                switch (actionType) {
                    case ActionType.SAVE_GAME:
                        return "Save Game";
                    case ActionType.LOAD_GAME:
                        return "Load Game";
                    case ActionType.PAUSE_GAME:
                        return "Pause Game";
                }
                return "invalid action type";
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

in order to prevent serialization issues when your code is changed.
Otherwise your already created scriptable objects will hold old data (due to them being serialized).

Another way is to use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to make a call like `actionButton1.text = action1.actionType.ToReadableString();` possible.